# Particular element-wise multiplication between matrix and vectors

Tags: matrix, vector, code-request

I have the following formula to implement $$\Sigma_{ij} = \rho_{ij}\sigma_i\sigma_j$$ where **no implicit summation** is implied. I have both the $\sigma$ vector and the $\rho$ matrix and I want to calculate the $\Sigma$ matrix.

To be pedantic what i need is a way to find the elements of the matrix $\Sigma$ such that, take for example the element $(1,2)$, this is given by the normal multiplication $$\Sigma_{12} = \rho_{12}\sigma_1\sigma_2$$

Specifically the vector is a $1\times 10$ vector and the matrix is $10\times 10$. At the end I want another $10\times10$ matrix defined as before.

> How can I do this?

Comment: Try `matrix KroneckerProduct[vector, vector]` or `vector matrix.DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[vector]]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher both of them seem to not work. In particular the KroneckerProduct of the two vectors yields a $1\times 100$ column vector which cannot be multiplied by the matrix. In the second case I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Your answer sparked something in my head: I converted the vector to a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements the elements of the vector and then multiplied row-by-columns diagMatrix.Matrix.diagMatrix and I seem to get a sensible answer!

Comment: "both of them seem to not work." What are you talking about? They _work_ (see below). `KroneckerProduct[vector, vector]` is a $10 \times 10$ matrix.

Comment: Ah, you are taking about a $1 \times 10$ vector. Then just use `Flatten` : `matrix KroneckerProduct[Flatten[vector], Flatten[vector]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just too long for a comment.

```
n = 1000;
matrix = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
vector = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n}];

A0 = Table[matrix[[i, j]] vector[[i]] vector[[j]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]; //
   AbsoluteTiming // First
A1 = matrix KroneckerProduct[vector, vector]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
A2 = vector matrix.DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[vector]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.32595
>
> 0.006415
>
> 0.006203

This shows that one should avoid `Table` if possible.

```
Max[Abs[A0 - A1]]
Max[Abs[A0 - A2]]
```

> 1.11022*10^-16
>
> 1.11022*10^-16

Comment: Yes, the first one worked pretty well! It gave the same result as per the solution I gave in the comments. Thank you very much!